# how to show tooltip content which is in childComponent from parentComponent angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, tooltip

I have created one component which is parent:-

```
@Component({
    selector: 'parent',
    templateUrl: '../views/parent.view.html'
})
export class ParentComponent {
    @ViewChild('primaryColorSample')
    primaryColorSample: AssetNoteComponent;
}
```

Parent html :-

```
<div> <a [tooltip]="primaryColorSample">add</a>
    <child #primaryColorSample></child>
</div>
```

child component :-

```
@Component({
    selector: 'child',
    templateUrl: '../views/child.view.html'
})
export class childComponent {

}
```

Child HTML :-

```
<tooltip-content #primaryColorSample [animation]="true" placement="left">
  <input type="text" name="child" required="true" />
  <button>save</button>
</tooltip-content>
```

I'm not able to use tooltip content from parent html, would you please suggest me how to do this.
I'm using ngx-tooltop and Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the doc and source code of ngx-tooltip, we can see the `[tooltip]` Input is of type string or TooltipContent component.

You could move the template of child, which is a TooltipContent, to the top of parent template, and remove `<child #primaryColorSample></child>`. It would work.

In your setup, you use `ViewChild` to get a reference to `Child` component, what you get in return is a reference to the child component class, not a string, not a TooltipContent component, so it didn't work.

Comment: Thank You @Rex..Yes that is working, so is it not possible to use tooltip inside child component ? or is there any other way to perform that because I need to use input and save inside childComponent and have to send data using output to the parent component.

Comment: There may be a way: keep the `<tooltip-content>` in the parent, but inside it, insert your child component with input and add button.

Comment: Thank you so much :) @Rex...why I didn't think about this idea.

Comment: @Sakura You are welcome. You will get the idea next time in other scenarios.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Declare an input in your child component ?

```
<child #primaryColorSample [tooltip]="primaryColorSample"></child>
```

Comment: it's not working..I'm passing input inside that add div <div> <a [tooltip]="primaryColorSample">add</a>
   <child #primaryColorSample></child>
  </div> from parent there I need to hover for child content.